# Calculate run length aggregated by subject ID conditional on observation == 1

Tags: r, aggregate

I am trying to use the `rle` function in R to calculate the run lengths for the variable `positive` in the example below, aggregated by the variable `id`.

Here is a toy dataset (that admittedly has a few quirks):

```
test <- c('id', 'positive')
test$id <- rep(1:3, c(24, 24, 24))
set.seed(123456)          
test$positive <- round(runif(72, 0, 1))

test <- data.frame(test)
test <- subset(test, select = -X.id.)
test <- subset(test, select = -X.positive.)    

result <- aggregate(positive ~ id, data = test, FUN = rle)
```

The way this currently is set up it reads the run lengths for all possible values (0 and 1) of the variable `positive`. Is it possible to condition this function such that it only evaluates the run lengths when `positive == 1`?

At the end of the day, I ultimately want to figure out how to count the number of instances in which **two or more** consecutive months were positive (`positive == 1`) for each subject.

UPDATE:

I have a variable called `event` that has values of 0 or 1. For each of the occurrences of two or more positives that were developed from the code featured in the suggestions below, is it possible to stratify our results such that if `event == 1` occurs during any of the positive months it would be classified differently than a run of positives in which `event == 0` for all of the months?

The toy dataset looks like this:

```
set.seed(123456)
x <- c(1, 2, 1)
test <- data.frame(id = rep(1:3, each = 24), positive = round(runif(72, 0, 1)), event = round(runif(72, 0, 1)))

results <- aggregate(positive ~ id + event, data = test, FUN=function(x) with(rle(x),   sum(lengths > 1 & values == 1)))
aggregate(positive ~ event, data = result, FUN=sum)
```

However, this code gives all possible permutations of event and positive, while I would like to delimit the results to counting only those occurrences of two or more consecutive positive months for which any `event == 1`. Alternatively, if it is easier to evaluate only the number of consecutive positive months for which all `event == 0` that would be a fine solution too.

Comment: I've edited my answer accordingly. Please check if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To count occurrences of two or more consecutive positives, use this:

```
aggregate(positive ~ id, data=test, FUN=function(x) with(rle(x), sum(lengths>=2 & values==1)))
```

(inspired in @sgibb's answer.)

EDIT: Counting the number of 2 or more consecutive positives such that any of them has event==1, separated by id:

Calculate the run to which each record belongs:

```
tmp <- within(test, run <- ave(positive, by=id, FUN=function(x)cumsum(c(1,diff(x)!=0))))

# id positive event run
#  1        1     1   1
#  1        1     0   1
#  1        0     1   2
#  1        0     0   2
#  1        0     1   2
#  1        0     0   2
```

For each id and each run mark if there was at least one record with `event==1` *and run length >= 2*:

```
tmp2 <- aggregate(event~id+positive+run, data=tmp, function(x)any(x>0) && length(x)>=2)

# id positive run event
#  2        0   1 FALSE
#  1        1   1  TRUE
#  3        1   1 FALSE
#  1        0   2  TRUE
#  3        0   2  TRUE
#  2        1   2  TRUE
```

Now simply count how many marked runs are there in each id and each kind of run (`positive==1` or `positive==0`):

```
aggregate(event~positive+id, tmp2, sum)

# positive id event
#        0  1     1
#        1  1     2
#        0  2     1
#        1  2     3
#        0  3     3
#        1  3     1
```

Comment: Very close -- thanks. Is it possible to limit the `run` variable to only mark those that are two or more consecutive positives and not include those that are runs of 0?

Comment: @Entropy, simply remove those rows from tmp2, like this: `tmp3 <- tmp2[tmp2[,"positive"]==1,]`, then use `aggregate(event~id, tmp3, sum)`. The output must match the result above, excluding rows where `positive==0`.

Comment: This counts runs where `positive==1` of length 1 (one observation or one month). Is it possible to restrict the final aggregate command to only sum those with **two or more** consecutive positives? For example, with the current `aggregate(event~id, tmp3, sum)` code ID#2 Run#6 includes only 1 observation and is currently being counted. Is it possible to avoid counting occurrences such as this in which only 1 isolated positive occurs?

Comment: @Entropy Fixed. Included condition `length(x)>=2` in `tmp2`. Thanks for spotting this. Checked ID#2 Run#6 and others.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?:

```
aggregate(positive ~ id, data=test, FUN=function(x) { 
  r <- rle(x); 
  return(r$length[r$value == 1])
})
#   id            positive
# 1  1       2, 1, 1, 7, 1
# 2  2 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2
# 3  3       1, 7, 1, 1, 1
```

Answer (score 1):

A `ddply` version for the 'at the end of the day' part:

```
library(plyr)
set.seed(123456)
test <- data.frame(id = rep(1:3, each = 24), positive = round(runif(72, 0, 1))) 

ddply(.data = test, .variables = .(id), function(x){
      rl <- rle(x$positive)
      sum(rl$length[rl$value == 1] > 1)
      }
)

#      id V1
#    1  1  2
#    2  2  5
#    3  3  1
```